# Proper way of getting function arguments with spaces and specials characters

Tags: batch-file

First time here, but dealing with batch codes from a long time.
I'd like to get some help developing a proper way to get correct parameters in a batch function.
In some functions, I usually need to get the parameters the way they are really passed, not "eating" any comma and not getting the script broked by any special characters. 
If the function has one parameter only, it's easy and everything is there in %* the way it should. 
But I usually I need to get some auxiliary paramters like variables or paths first and, so, I set the argument that might have some special stuff to the last position.
This is the only way I've found to use and treat complex arguments. But implementing this is always a trouble. 
When I thought that I've found a best way by using FOR /F and tokens with *, I got problems when the first arguments (like paths) have spaces (or any other delimiter) because quotes are ignored then.
The only way I can achieve what I want by now is getting each numbered argument and its length then subtracting from all arguments, getting then the "rest argument" that I want, but that is some kind expensive, because I have to call String Len code many times. 
Is there a way to use FOR /F delimiting by space but respecting quoted parameters with spaces?
Or anyone else knows a better and proper way of achieving what I want?!
Here's some code to illustrate the problem:

```
:: When no space in first arguments everything works
CALL :MyFunc arg1 argument2 c:\path\to\arg3 c:\path\toarg4 ,run, anything "here" even specials "&" like "|<>" and single" quotes
:: But spaces broke first arguments
CALL :MyFunc arg1 "argument 2" c:\path\to\arg3 "c:\spaced path\to arg4" ,run, anything "here" even specials "&" like "|<>" and single" quotes
GOTO :EOF

:MyFunc
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Checking if everything is there
ECHO %*
ECHO.
SET params=%*
ECHO Traditional way of parsing parameters works for first params:
ECHO 1:%1 2:%2 3:%3 4:%4 
ECHO But how to get rest this way?
ECHO.
ECHO Trying to get through FOR /F and tokens with * to get rest
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4*" %%a IN ("!params!") DO SET "arg1=%%~a" & SET "arg2=%%~b" & SET "arg3=%%c" & SET "arg4=%%~d" & SET "argrest=%%e"
ECHO It will work for non spaced first params but not for parameters with spaces quoted because delims is space
ECHO Parsing Desired Arguments With FOR: 
ECHO 1:!arg1! 2:!arg2! 3:!arg3! 4:!arg4! Rest:!argrest!
ECHO.
GOTO :EOF
```

Result:

```
Checking if everything is there
arg1 argument2 c:\path\to\arg3 c:\path\toarg4 ,run, anything "here" even specials "&" like "|<>" and single" quotes

Traditional way of parsing parameters works for first params:
1:arg1 2:argument2 3:c:\path\to\arg3 4:c:\path\toarg4
But how to get rest this way?

Trying to get through FOR /F and tokens with * to get rest
It will work for non spaced first params but not for parameters with spaces quoted because delims is space
Parsing Desired Arguments With FOR:
1:arg1 2:argument2 3:c:\path\to\arg3 4:c:\path\toarg4 Rest:,run, anything "here" even specials "&" like "|<>" and single" quotes

Checking if everything is there
arg1 "argument 2" c:\path\to\arg3 "c:\spaced path\to arg4" ,run, anything "here" even specials "&" like "|<>" and single" quotes

Traditional way of parsing parameters works for first params:
1:arg1 2:"argument 2" 3:c:\path\to\arg3 4:"c:\spaced path\to arg4"
But how to get rest this way?

Trying to get through FOR /F and tokens with * to get rest
It will work for non spaced first params but not for parameters with spaces quoted because delims is space
Parsing Desired Arguments With FOR:
1:arg1 2:argument 3:2" 4:c:\path\to\arg3 Rest:"c:\spaced path\to arg4" ,run, anything "here" even specials "&" like "|<>" and single" quotes
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Whilst it's good that you've edited to include the resulting output, it is likely that we could all copy your code and run it to see that anyhow. What you should do, is to provide the exact output you wish to have, in order we can clearly see where the differences lie, and whether it's possible to do it. In my opinion however, I'll say that there is certainly no simple, robust, one size fits all, method of parsing all arguments with any characters. Currently therefore, solutions would only need to deal with the exact code and arguments you've provided, and I presume that's not what you wanted!

Comment: It is *very* difficult to safely handle all arguments! It is good practice to enclose arguments in `""` in order to protect token separators (like _space_, _tab_, `,`, `;`, `=`) special characters (like `(`, `)`, `&`, `^`, `<`, `>`, `|`). But it becomes horrible when you have unbalanced quotes `"`, particularly because of immediate expansion of argument references `%1`/`%~1`, etc. And there is the nasty `^`-doubling by the command `call`. To easily overcome all these problems, you could pass a *variable name* as an argument, then use something like `!%~1!` in your function…

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting. I agree with aschipfl. Passing by reference instead value is the best and simplest way. Other ways is usually too much expensive and they will spend more process time treating parameters than the main function purpose. I just was hoping for the existence of some magic trick unknown by me to achieve that, lol, because the FOR /F approach was too close to what I needed, handling * in a pretty good way but for the first tokens is impossible to get them split like default batch parameters passing functionality. Thanks again.